# How to select with rows with maxium value for column by grouping them based on other column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have dataset like below dataset (df).  I want to select only the rows with maximum unixtime for give date for according to the coordinates.

How can this be this done

```
    coord           date             unixtime         A              B
0   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-04  1572825600000   1.24             0      
1   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-04  1572847200000   1.87             0.2        
2   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-04  1572868800000   7.56             0.3        
3   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-04  1572890400000   10.06            0      
4   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-05  1572912000000   6.94             0      
5   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-05  1572933600000   5.34             0      
6   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-05  1572955200000   1.39             0      
7   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-05  1572976800000   0.76             0.2        
8   47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-06  1572998400000   0.63             0      
9   25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-04  1572825600000   3.61             0.7        
10  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-04  1572847200000   5.28             0      
11  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-04  1572868800000   6.94             0      
12  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-04  1572890400000   5.28             0      
13  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-05  1572912000000   2.50             0.6        
14  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-05  1572933600000   1.67             0      
15  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-05  1572955200000   3.89             0      
16  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-05  1572976800000   2.50             0      
17  25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-06  1572998400000   3.06             0.4
```

**Expected Output**

```
      coord             date        unixtime    A                    B  
    47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-04  1572890400000   10.06            0              
    47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-05  1572976800000   0.76             0.2        
    47.62042:122.3494   2019-11-06  1572998400000   0.63             0              
    25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-04  1572890400000   5.28             0          
    25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-05  1572976800000   2.50             0      
    25.27699:55.29625   2019-11-06  1572998400000   3.06             0.4
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `drop_duplicates`

```
df=df.sort_values('unixtime').drop_duplicates(['coord','date'],keep='last')
Out[145]: 
                coord        date       unixtime      A    B
3   47.62042:122.3494  2019-11-04  1572890400000  10.06  0.0
12  25.27699:55.29625  2019-11-04  1572890400000   5.28  0.0
7   47.62042:122.3494  2019-11-05  1572976800000   0.76  0.2
16  25.27699:55.29625  2019-11-05  1572976800000   2.50  0.0
8   47.62042:122.3494  2019-11-06  1572998400000   0.63  0.0
17  25.27699:55.29625  2019-11-06  1572998400000   3.06  0.4
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['coord','date']).unixtime.idxmax()]
Out[146]: 
                coord        date       unixtime      A    B
12  25.27699:55.29625  2019-11-04  1572890400000   5.28  0.0
16  25.27699:55.29625  2019-11-05  1572976800000   2.50  0.0
17  25.27699:55.29625  2019-11-06  1572998400000   3.06  0.4
3   47.62042:122.3494  2019-11-04  1572890400000  10.06  0.0
7   47.62042:122.3494  2019-11-05  1572976800000   0.76  0.2
8   47.62042:122.3494  2019-11-06  1572998400000   0.63  0.0
```